# How to find specific files in a folder using python

Tags: python

There are different files in a folder, I would like to print files which are ended with `IHDRT.exr`. The correct answer for this job is as shown bellow:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import glob

    for file in glob.glob("*.exr"):
        if file.endswith('iHDRT.exr'):
            print(file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all files of a directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

Comment: endswidth --> endswith

Comment: (iHDRT.exr') --> ('iHDRT.exr'), you forget the first  **'**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use `glob.glob('*iHDRT.exr')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob

for file in glob.glob("*.exr"):
    if file.endswith('iHDRT.exr'):
            ^^^^^^^^
        print(file)
```

Its `endswith` and not `endswidth`

Answer (score 1):

Use **endswith**, not endswidth! Error spelling